# DbSet Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, data-access-layer, 3-tier

I'm trying to make a universal 3-tier application with generic repositories for any data provider/orm. I just rewrote the code and got stuck on the error of Object reference not set to an instance of an object while trying make action in DbSet. I'm completely confused.. at least nudge me in the right direction.

**Repository.cs**

```
 public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{

    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
    private IDbSet<T> _objectset;

    private IDbSet<T> DbSet
    {
        get { return _objectset ?? (_objectset = UnitOfWork.Context.Set<T>()); }
    }
public List<T> GetAll()
    {
        try
        {
            return DbSet.ToList();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in repository while attempts get all elements");
        }
    }
}
```

**EFUnitOfWork.cs**

```
 public class EfUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    public EfUnitOfWork()
    {
        Context = new AppContext();
    }

    public DbContext Context { get; set; }

    public void Commit()
    {
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }

    public bool LazyLoadingEnabled
    {
        get { return Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled; }
        set { Context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = value; }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

**AppContext.cs**

```
 public class AppContext : DbContext, IDbContext
{
    public AppContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<AppContext,            Configuration>());
        Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    }

    public DbSet<Logic> Logics { get; set; }

    public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

    public new IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        return base.Set<TEntity>();
    }
}
```

**IDbContext.cs**

```
public interface IDbContext
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    int SaveChanges();
    void Dispose();
}
```

**Configuration.cs**

```
class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<AppContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(AppContext context)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: How do you set property UnitOfWork  in your IRepository object?

Comment: IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: DbSet.ToList(); or any action with DbSet in Repository.cs. In locals _objectset - null, DbSet - NullRegExp, UnitOfWork - null.

Comment: @MaksMartynov i see the property but i don't see how it gets value? Later in your DbSet property you are calling  UnitOfWork.Context which i suspect causes null reference exception if UnitOfWork is null

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you change the `Repository` to expect `IUnitOfWork` in the constructor as it is not valid without it.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    public Repository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;)
    {
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }
    public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get { return _unitOfWork; } }
}
```

`IDbContext` should be defined as implementing `IDisposable` (and remove the `Dispose` method from the interface definition)

```
public interface IDbContext : IDisposable
{
    IDbSet<TEntity> Set<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    int SaveChanges();
}
```

The following line of code from `AppContext` will have the effect of disabling lazy loading because lazy loading is implemented by proxies

```
Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```